# MSBuild command line reference reserved property

Tags: msbuild

I'd like to turn on MvcBuildViews checking for overnight builds without the need to edit project files. I have to use $(MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot) due to project name/namespace collisions.

```
MSBuild /p MvcBuildViews=true;IntermediateOutputPath=C:\Temp\$(MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot)  MySolution.sln
```

From my testing so far the reserved property does not get evaluated early enough.
Is there a work around ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an $(MsBuildProperty) as an command line argument to MsBuild.  For a work around, I have a pattern that you'd apply to all of your projects and give you greater control of the build process.  See [common targets and props files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164312.aspx).

These are files that include logic and tasks common to many projects in your solution.  You use the MsBuild [<Import />](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) task to import a common property file at the top of your projects to consolidate all the common MsBuild $(Property) values from your projects.  Things like `<IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Temp\$(MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot)</IntermediateOutputPath>` would go here.

At the bottom of your projects you'd [<Import />](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) your .targets script that contains any custom MsBuild targets or tasks.  Things like a common AfterBuild target could go here.

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) , Common.props ))\Common.props" />
  <!-- Project contents -->
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) , Common.targets ))\Common.targets" />
</Project>
```

A common targets file is an MsBuild script, similar to a project file, that contains custom MsBuild targets to be imported by your projects.